# Which Azure Storage is used in DataStax ASTRA DB

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

There is little documentation on how ASTRA DB stores data. So, i could not do much research on this. I wanted to know which of the storage options do ASTRA DB use to store data in azure blob. The storage options are

1. LRS(Locally Redundant Storage) - copies data synchronously three times within a single physical location in the primary region
2. ZRS(Zone-redundancy storage) - Copies data synchronously across three Azure availability zones in the primary region
3. GRS(Geo-redundant storage) - Intermediate option with failover capabilities in a secondary region
4. GZRS(Geo-zone-redundant storage) - Optimal data protection that includes both GRS and ZRS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Serverless databases are automatically replicated across three availability zones - see [About your Astra DB database](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/plan/planning.html).

> Each Astra DB database uses replication across three availability
> zones within the launched region to promote uptime and ensure data
> integrity.

This would mean ZRS in the case of Azure.

Comment: I believe that it's more about Cassandra replication...

Comment: @AlexOtt DataStax published a white paper discussion Astra DB's architecture: https://www.datastax.com/resources/whitepaper/astra-serverless. Cassandra is a monolith. Astra breaks the traditional monolith into services that can scale up and down. Replication in Astra works differently than Apache Cassandra.